# How to mount individual card elements stripe.js?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments, payment-gateway, stripe.js

I am trying to mount individual card elements in order to get desired design, but when I mount multiple elements only last one was mounted.

My procedure follows as below:

```
var stripe = Stripe(STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY);
var elements = stripe.elements();

var cardNumber = elements.create('cardNumber');
var cardExpiry = elements.create('cardExpiry');
var cardCvc = elements.create('cardCvc');

// Add an instance of the card Element into the `card-element` <div>
cardNumber.mount('#card-element');
cardExpiry.mount('#card-element');
cardCvc.mount('#card-element');
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to use a different container for each element, otherwise it will overwrite the previous one when you mount it.

In your case you'd need 3 containers (e.g. #card-number-element, #card-expiry-element and #card-cvc-element) and then change your last 3 lines to this for example:

```
cardNumber.mount('#card-number-element');
cardExpiry.mount('#card-expiry-element');
cardCvc.mount('#card-cvc-element');
```

Comment: and how can we pass  this as a card element in params